# CPU speed lower then it especially when stressed

Tags: windows-7, cpu, bios, cpu-speed

I have 2 identical PCs, i7-4790k, 32GB RAM running Win7 pro.
When idle one runs at 4.4GHz (multiplier x44) but the other one (the bad one) show speed of only 4.2GHz (multiplier x42). The matter worsen when CPUs are stressed the good one drops to 4.2GHz (has it should) but the bad one drops to 3GHz, I've checked everywhere Windows power settings, BIOS settings they are all identical (as far as I know), any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: Are the systems overclocked ? The multiplier suggests they are different models if it's the default one.

Comment: No overclocking. As for the multiplier, In the BIOS setting the multipliers  are set (as they should) to 44,44,43,42 on both machines. i.e. idle speed (or when running 1 or 2 cores) supposed to be 4.4GHz (like in the good one).

Comment: Thermal throttling? Bad thermal paste between the cpu and cooler? Check the temperatures of both processors under the same load, using CpuZ or any other free tool. While thermal throttling usually happens in laptops, it might be happening in your computer too.

Comment: OK. it seems that the temperatures are different, when resting around 90C in the bad one in comparison to around 40C in the good one. do you think i need to change the thermal paste? cause fan seems to work fine (around 3000rpm on both when stressed), should i change the fan as well?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the details in the comments, the problem is now clear. Your CPU is overheating. In no circumstance it should reach that temperature.

You need to remove the heat-sink, clean it up, add thermal paste and make sure it is fixed properly (is in good contact with CPU surface). Your CPU should not exceed 60C when at load if your cooling is proper.

Comment: I replaced thermal paste and it looks better (no speed drop) but base speed when idle still 4.2 and not 4.4 any other suggestions?

Comment: What's the temperature now when idle and when at load ?

Comment: Sorry it took me sometime to reply, I've changed the PSUs and fans on both computers (bad and good). the bad one when idle has a temperature of 40c (the other one is only 30c) could that be the case?
I also notice differences in CPU core voltage but in there the bad one has a higher value (1.104v compare to 0.756v).

Comment: Can you run CPU-Z on both systems and give us a screenshot ?